# I have a file : swagger json with weird null at the end of file

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a web api core application described with swagger.
I get a strange null value after accessing swagger.json

Comment: {
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "SO.API.Institution",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/institutions/create": {
}...etc...etc.etc

}null

Comment: Parser error on line 584
end of the stream or a document separator is expected Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

Comment: I have just a simple   services.AddSwaggerGen(); and a   app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Identity API V1");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.